# How to use String.format() in Java to replicate tab "\t"?

Tags: java, syntax, tabs, format

I'm printing data line by line and want it to be organized like a table.

I initially used `firstName + ", " + lastName + "\t" + phoneNumber`.

But for some of the larger names, the phone number gets pushed out of alignment

I'm trying to use String.format() to achieve this effect. Can anyone tell me the format syntax to use?

I tried `String.format("%s, %s, %20s", firstName, lastName, phoneNumber)`, but that's not what I want. I want it to look like this:

John, Smith            123456789

Bob, Madison         123456789

Charles, Richards  123456789

Edit:
These answers seem to work for System.out.println(). But I need it to work for a JTextArea. I'm using textArea.setText()

Worked it out. JTextArea doesn't use monospaced fonts by default. I used setFont() to change that, and now it works like a charm. Thank you all for the solutions.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

consider using a negative number for your length specifier: `%-20s`. For example:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     String[] firstNames = {"Pete", "Jon", "Fred"};
     String[] lastNames = {"Klein", "Jones", "Flinstone"};
     String phoneNumber = "555-123-4567";

      for (int i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++) {
        String foo = String.format("%-20s %s", lastNames[i] + ", " + 
             firstNames[i], phoneNumber);
        System.out.println(foo);
      }   
   }
```

returns

```
Klein, Pete          555-123-4567
Jones, Jon           555-123-4567
Flinstone, Fred      555-123-4567
```

Comment: This doesn't work for JTextAreas for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: Found out. It needed to be monospaced font.

Comment: @ask: indeed. You might be better off with a simple JTable for this display of data.

Comment: I know. It's for an assignment and they are forcing me to use text areas. But I'm trying to make it look nice.

Answer (score 13):

Try putting the **width into second placeholder with `-` sign for right padding** as:

```
  String.format("%s, %-20s %s", firstName, lastName, phoneNumber)
```

This will give the specified width to the second argument(last name) with right padding and phone number will start after the specified width string only.

**EDIT:** Demo:

```
String firstName = "John";
String lastName = "Smith";
String phoneNumber = "1234456677";
System.out.println(String.format("%s, %-20s %s",firstName, lastName, phoneNumber));
```

prints:

> John, Smith               1234456677

Comment: Doesn't work. This makes the phone number start 30 chars after the ",". But the, itself is dependent on the first name's length.

Comment: @ask What do you mean exactly? For firstName = `John` lastName = `Smith` and phoneNumber  as `1234456677`, it prints : `John, Smith                                   1234456677`. The with for last name field is assigned with 20 chars length so I see 15 white spaces appearing after `Smith` and before the phone number. I updated the answer with an example demo. If you are loking for something different, let me know.

Comment: Thanks. It works for System.out.println(). But when I set this text to a textarea, it doesn't work.

Comment: @ask: Just curious, what difference you found in this answer and the other answer, you accepted?

Comment: @ask: This is fine. I just thought if you noticed any difference or preferred the concatenation :)

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative is loop the names list, calculate the maximum length of the String, and add whitespaces as needed after every name to ensure that all the numbers begin at the same column.

Using tabs has the disavantage that you cannot know `a priori` how many whitespace are equivalent to a tab, since it is dependent of the editor.