# Android text justification issue within checkbox

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, android-checkbox

In one of the activity of my application, I am displaying user names with their points in front of the names.

The name may have different number of characters, but I want the strings to end at the same place.

I am **able to provide correct number of spaces and the strings are equal in character lengths** but the **characters take uneven space** and **ruin the symmetry of the strings**.

Is there any work around for this?

**Here's the code** :

```
private String separateNamePoints{
    String text="";

            //text is separated by ,
    String[]splittedRawText=rawText.split(",");

    String name=(splittedRawText)[0];
    String points=(splittedRawText)[1];

    int pointsLength=points.length();
    int reqSpaceLength=40-name.length();

    String space="";

    for(int i=0;i<reqSpaceLength;i++){
        space+=" ";
    }

    if(pointsLength==1)
        space+="   ";
    else if(pointsLength==2)
        space+="  ";
    else if(pointsLength==3)
        space+=" ";

    text=name+space+points;

    return text;
}
```

And **here's the image** :

[image]

Comment: Do not expose your design.It may copied :)

Comment: @Baadshah What if he deploy his app? Can't copied?

Comment: Why don't you align the user points to right side of the window and the names to the left ?

Comment: If you show your xml file then I can show you how you do it.

Comment: @osayilgan Design requirement.

Comment: @Shail You should modify your row. use two TextViews will solve your problem...

Comment: There is an easy way to do it, use two text views one aligning left and the other to right.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292575/android-textview-justify-text

Comment: Can you paste your list view's item layout?

Comment: What if I am setting everything dynamically!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android do not provide complete text justification**.

In this case, need to create a custom control containing separate edittexts to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways you can handle this..

- Your approach

In here, you can try using `String.format()` to format as per requirement .. here [read this for ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

- You can use 2 textViews and use alignment to solve your problem..

Comment: I have to set everything dynamically!!

Comment: For, case 1 .. have you read the link provided ?? Just try out first.. check [this for ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13789157/2345913)..For case 2 ... follow code snippet provided by @Dimmerg.. That will do the trick..

Comment: It does not help. It gives the same problem that I face with the logic above. The console and logcat give proper strings but in the textview of android, texts are not justified.

Comment: I think need to use separate textviews somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this xml for list item and write adapter for this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/points" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have to set everything dynamically!!

Comment: What do you mean? You can change any values in source of adapter and call notifyDatasetChanged() - list will updated according your changes.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will work fine. I think your input string having some space after the number.
please try with this

```
String[]splittedRawText=rawText.trim().split(",");
```

Comment: I have mentioned that I am able to get correct number of spaces...that's not the problem.

Comment: your input name is not exceed the length 40...so you have to trim if the space in name and point.

Comment: no I have checked them by printing. they are having equal number of characters.