# Why Writting on txt file is different from console?

Tags: java

I want to save my `ArrayList` in a txt file, so i used `PrintWriter`. It is like a table, so I used the `String.format` method. When writing my data on the console, then it is perfect. But when writing on txt file it was different.

Why is it different when writing in txt file from console. Just see in below image?

[image: different txt output]

Comment: Please include the code you're using.

Comment: couldn't you add your image here? i cannot see any image by click on your link....

Comment: I embedded the image + added formatting to your question + some grammar corrections. Please let me know if my changes are unjustified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because of tabs (`\t`) you are using. Apparently notepad has a different way of displaying tabs than the console. You might be able to use `String.format` to do some formatting, instead of adding tabs yourself, just check [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for that.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789141/how-to-use-string-format-in-java-to-replicate-tab-t) for a solution, for example:

```
String.format("%s, %s, %-20s%n", firstName, lastName, phoneNumber)
```

EDIT
Additional tip: you can add %n in the format string to get a platform specific newline (Added in above example).

Comment: When I compare the images, it rather looks like an problem with **new line** `\r`, `\n`...just sayin....

Comment: I think you are mistaken. The first screenshot shows the numbered console lines, separated by a line of whitespace. The second one shows Notepad, with FUBAR formatting.