# Not printing correct format

Tags: java

So I am making a username password database to write it in a file:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class createfile {

private Formatter x;

public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Formatter("okey.fil");

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("error get it right");
    }
}
public void addRecords(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of records");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    for(int counter = 1; counter<=num; counter++){
        String username = input.nextLine();
        String email = input.nextLine();
        String userpass = input.nextLine();
        String emailpass = input.nextLine();
        x.format("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", username,"\t", email,"\t", userpass,"\t", emailpass, "\n");

    }

}
public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}
}

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createfile f = new createfile();
    f.openFile();
    f.addRecords();
    f.closeFile();
    }
}
```

Problem is, it outputs incorrect in wrong format:
i'll use 2 for number of records (num = 2)
and the strings will equal the same to what it is asking for (username = username, emailpass = emailpass...)
and this is the output:

```
        username        email   userpass
emailpass       username2       email2  userpass2
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4gf148gr

Comment: I always though that one of main reasons to use `printf` is to avoid `\t`. Also what is the point in passing string literals as argument instead of placing them directly in format?

Comment: yeah I was trying different ways of \t to see if it would fix the format

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789141/how-to-use-string-format-in-java-to-replicate-tab-t